# How to fix warning failed to connect to lvmetad no such file or directory falling back to internal scanning

Tags: boot, gnome, gui, lvm

My Ubuntu laptop which was working fine until recently. My desktop disappeared and all desktop icons are gone. All I have access to is the terminal. In an attempt to fix the problem, I installed GNOME but it made the computer give the error:

```
Warning! Failed to connect to lvmetad.  No such file or directory   
Falling back to internal scanning.
```

I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to start tty1 but I can't get to a graphical user interface. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?.

Comment: Type this command "sudo startx" when you get to your command line interface.

Comment: Does it bring back your GUI?

Comment: No it didn't help.